# input from keyboard to a text file in c?? The Code compiles but *EOF* don't works?

Tags: c, fopen

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  FILE * pFile;
  char ch;
  pFile = fopen ("G:\\ IJLAL.txt","w+");
  while((ch = getchar())!=EOF)
    putc(ch,pFile);
  fclose(pFile);
  return 0;
}
```

can you specify the problem???
I am totally new to *fopen* function.
and please help me with this thing

Answer (score 2):

The `getchar()` function returns an `int` value, not a `char`. By forcing it into a `char` variable, you are making it impossible to detect the EOF.

Just change `char ch` to `int ch` and it will work fine.*

---

- Actually, you will probably still have problems with the file name. Are you sure it should contain a space? And are you aware that `\\` is encoded as a single backslash character?

Comment: Not working. The **EOF** don't closes the run window. i just put $EOF$ at the end but it continuous waiting for me to enter more.

Comment: i have made static text files with that edting. Now i want to enter the data from keyboard.

Comment: @Ahmad You put $EOF$ at the end? I'm not even sure what you mean by that. On a command line terminal, the EOF is usually indicated by hitting Control-D. With a sensible filename, your code will compile and run without any problems.

Comment: Wait a minute; Control-C aborts the program altogether. If Control-D doesn't work, [try Control-Z instead](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16136400/1679849).

Comment: But the program do saves the texts that is entered first than Control-C....Control-D doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

According to the C99 standard (7.19.1.3):

> EOF which expands to an integer constant expression, with type int and
>   a negative value, that is returned by several functions to indicate
>   end-of-file, that is, no more input from a stream;

The point is that EOF is out of the range of `unsigned char`.  I am sure this was done intentionally so that all 256 basic and extended ASCII characters can still be returned, and are distinct from `EOF`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

1 - Check fopen() return values -> print errno value (perror)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
    int     c;
    bool    run;
    FILE    *fd;

    run = true;
    fd = fopen("/tmp/file.txt", "w+");
    if (fd == NULL)
    {
        perror("fopen");
        return (1);
    }
    while (run == true)
    {
        c = getchar(); // Press ctrl + D for exit
        run = (!feof(stdin) && !ferror(stdin));
        if (run == true)
            putc(c, fd);
    }
    fclose(fd);
}
```

And if you want you can see this [link](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2952).