# Invalid input for std::cin

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

The following code is intended to concatenate words entered by the user.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main() {
    // insert code here...

    std::string s;
    std::string concString;
    while (std::cin >> s)
    {
        concString = concString + s;
    }
    std::cout << concString << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am stuck in this while loop during execution because of which I am not able to print the concatenated string. How do I exit this loop? What is an invalid input for std::cin?

Comment: Use 'break' in a conditional statement to get out of a while loop. The condition could be anything from the maximum number of words read or a specific word encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a loop like that is stopped by *end of file*, rather than invalid input.

In a *nix environment, you can usually send an end of file to the terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, and at a windows console, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16136924/1084944

You could, however, implement your own additional way to signify end of input. For example, having your users enter a blank line when done, or the word `quit` or such. Once you've chosen one, you should communicate that to the user, and you will have to structure your loop to be able to detect these conditions and exit.