# How to get the number of characters or lines by the CHARACTER COUNTING and LINE COUNTING programs in C?

Tags: c

I just started writing C programs and I am taking help of The C Programming book written by Dennis Ritchie. When I tried to run the program for COUNTING characters or new lines, i was expecting some numbers as solutions but it didn't happen, instead it just allowed me to enter characters, with no value( of the number of lines/ characters) in return. 
I am new to programming.
I would appreciate some help to get me through.

**character counting**

```
#include <stdio.h>

main( )
{
      long nc;

      nc=0;
      while (getchar( ) != EOF)
               ++nc;
      printf( "%1d\n",  nc );
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I have added the code. Please check it out.

Comment: Try to Ctrl + D when you're done typing ;)

Comment: What does ctrl+D do? BTW I'm using Windows.

Comment: Ctrl + D is an EOF in a command shell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send EOF via Windows terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136400/how-to-send-eof-via-windows-terminal)

Comment: Type CTRL+z for EOF in a Windows command shell.

Comment: Few additional possible problems: (1) your `main` doesn't conform to the **C** standard. (2) your `printf` format tag `%1d` is wrong, should be `%ld` for argument of type `long`.  (3) did you intend your code also to count "invisible" characters (blanks, newlines)?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the line

```
while (getchar( ) != EOF)
```

Your program is expecting an EOF (End Of File) before printing the counter.

Therefore you should type your text then **Ctrl + D** (EOF in a *nix command shell) or **Ctrl + Z** (Windows) to cut your input.

Then your counter will be printed.

Regards

Comment: Ctrl+ Z prints ^Z on the screen. But I just tried ctrl+2 and it took me back to the code. What to do next? I know may sound silly but I really don't know much right now :)

Comment: Are you using the Windows CMD ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are confused with sending input to your program. Your code reads characters one by one from so called STDIN until it reads EOF (End-Of-File) marker. Usually STDIN - is a keyboard, so whatever you type appears to be read by `getchar()`. If you wish to send EOF - press Ctrl+D (unix systems). Another alternative - use prefilled text file and use it as STDIN for your program via redirection:

```
$ ./a.out < my_input.txt
```

This approach works well both on *nix and win systems.

Comment: Did you mean `./a.out < my_input.txt` ?

Comment: Oh, yes :) Thanks!