# using cin with while

Tags: loops, c++11, cin

everyone! I recently tried a piece of code from [C++ Primer, 5th edition]. This code is at chapter 3.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    string word;
    while(cin >> word) {
        cout << word << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then, the book says: "...Once we hit end-of-file (or valid input), we fall out of the while." Surprisingly, I can never jump out from the while statement when trying this code in Visual Studio C++ 2017.

My question is: give what input will jump out from the loop? This book is very famous and read by many people, so I believe there is no error in the code.

Thank you!

Comment: Related (maybe dupe) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136400/how-to-send-eof-via-windows-terminal

Comment: The end-of-file key on Windows is typically `Ctrl-Z`. You usually need to press it on an empty line, and possibly end with a newline.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks a lot! It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In console you can simulate EOF flag. In UNIX systems it is Ctrl+D, in Windows Ctrl+Z. When you type this in the console, program will behave like it has just reached end of input file.