# End of File Input Python

Tags: python, eof

I am trying to solve Kattis problem. The full problem is found in the link: https://open.kattis.com/problems/addingwords

The part of the problem that I'm confused with is : "Input is a sequence of up to 2000 commands, one per line, ending at end of file."

What would be the code for this input? I tried doing this:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    #print('something')
```

After this, I continued the program as normal within the indentation from above. My question is, how would I test whether the program is working in cmd? I want to test a few cases, but when I input something, the command prompt keeps waiting for other results instead of printing anything out. And when I press control C the program ends abruptly. How are we supposed to check whether the program is working while taking in user input till end of file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `readlines()` is eager not lazy. That means it will read the entire file into memory (until EOF) and then split it into lines and return a list of those lines. So when working with interactive stdin, `sys.stdin.readline()` will wait until the end of stdin (Ctrl-D on linux/macOS, Ctrl+Z on windows).

But there is no need for `readlines()` (and in fact, [you almost should never use it](https://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html)). Iterating over a file object by default does so by lines:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    print('got line!')
```

The docs even [admit that you should do this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines). If you do need all lines in a list, then just do `list(sys.stdin)`.

Comment: so after writing a few input commands in cmd and pressing Ctrl-D, the output should be displayed?

Comment: Yes if you use `readlines()` (or `list(sys.stdin)`). But don't do that!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136400/how-to-send-eof-via-windows-terminal (if you're on windows)