# Shift + Enter vs Enter in console

Tags: c, shift, enter

I am trying to catch all characters that I input via my `stdin` stream except EOF. I want to input a multi-line text: each line with `\n` at the end.

```
int getline(char s[])
{
    printf("Call-getline()\n");

    int c;
    int idx=0;

    while((c=getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        s[idx++] = c;
    }

    printf("\n-EOF found--\n");

    s[idx] = '\0';

    return idx;
}
```

I don't know how to get rid of the `\n` that I get when i press enter, and I was wondering if `shif+enter` vs `enter alone` makes any difference. I read about what it does in Microsoft Word: new paragraph vs newline.

Comment: This answer: [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221) shows how to remove the final newline from a string. It doesn't matter that you didn't use `fgets`, and is safe when there isn't a newline there. So that would be `s[strcspn(s, "\n")] = 0;`

Comment: Yes, it is my mistake. There should only be `s[idx] = '\0'` because when the loop exits, the `idx` is already incremented by one.

Comment: @WeatherVane , `s[--idx] = '\0'` won't work always as the codeblocks console will always push a newline in any input stream when you press `enter`?

Comment: That overwrites the `enter` (newline). But if it isn't there, it either overwrites a character you want, or if the there wasn't any input, indexs `s[-1]` which is bad. But the comment I was referring to has been deleted, although it correctly identified a problem with `s[++idx] = '\0';`

Comment: I don't know. Windows console does not respond to Ctrl-Enter, and Shift-Enter does the same as Enter. Enter is *already* a "control character", which can be typed as Ctrl-M.

Comment: Oh, i got it. I also edit my question. Also, i wanted to know if there is any difference of sending the string using `ctrl+enter` or `enter alone`. How are they interpreted different by the console. Is any difference? I can't find any.

Comment: Your `getline` function is unsafe because it does not check array bounds.

Comment: Thank you! So there is no difference.

Comment: @IanAbbott you are totally right, but i have my  `char s[100]` in my main function and i take care always to input less or equal characters from my keyboard! This example's purpose is learning only!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221) was linked in the comments, which show you the solution.

However, I want to point out one other thing here. A common way of ending the input is by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, which will send the EOF to the program. Or at least most (all?) *nix terminals do. But that's a detail specific for the terminal you're using, so you have to read the documentation for your particular terminal.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58064046/6699433) answer, which tells you about how to do it on Windows. Unfortunately, the answer is basically that you cannot do it in a good way.

Comment: I am using Windows, so i tried with `CTRL + Z` on my last line it doesn't work. Ex:`Here is the text as if i was to input
and so forth
and here i put ^Z ` and afterwords i press enter. Nothing happends, it just go to the next line

Comment: On Windows, Ctrl-Z only works immediately after Enter was pressed, and needs another Enter too.

Comment: So there is normal that it won't works as long as `Ctrl-Z` is not the first element of the line followed by key press `ENTER`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, we can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to exit on visual studio and Dev C++ console
otherwise if we talk about CMD then you should write exit followed by an Enter