# entering EOF in istream

Tags: c++, io, eof

I was asked a question to write a function which takes and returns an `istream&`. The function should read the stream until it hits `EOF` and the value read should be printed with standard output.

Here is my code which works nearly fine:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<istream>


std::istream& fun(std::istream &ob)
{
    std::string s;
    while((ob>>s)&&(!ob.eof()))
        std::cout<<s<<'\n';
    return ob;
}

int main()
{
    std::istream &obj = fun(std::cin);
    return 0;
}
```

The only part which is not happening is program (`istream`) reaching to `EOF` - I have to manually enter `ctrl + d` on  the terminal to stop the loop - is there any other way around to do this?

Comment: I'm confused what precisely your question. Your function implements the functionality described in your first paragraph. Do you want it terminate **before** `EOF` instead? Or are you asking if there is an alternate way to send an `EOF` from your shell?

Comment: Almost Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136400/how-to-send-eof-via-windows-terminal

Comment: Note: `while((ob>>s)&&(!ob.eof()))` is a bit more than necessary. Detection of EOF is covered by testing `ob>>s`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the expected behavior.

Assuming you're in a Unix-y environment, you could alternatively pipe input to your program's stdin via redirection from the shell:

```sh
$ ./my_program < ./some_file.txt
```

Or, for the [`cat` abusers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat),

```sh
$ cat ./some_file.txt | ./my_program
```

This is essentially equivalent to executing `my_program` and then manually typing out the contents of `some_file.txt` followed by `CTRL+D`.

Comment: This is exactly I was looking for - an alternate way where `ctrl + d` is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

That's expected.

Ctrl+D is how you signal EOF.

Otherwise how would the terminal know that you wish to stop providing input? Where would EOF actually be?