# Scanner.hasNextLine - always true

Tags: java, java-8

I need to read data from standard input.
And I want to print it to standard output.
I use Scanner for this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int countLines = 1;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            sb.append(countLines).append(" ").append(line);
        }
        System.out.println("finish");
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        scanner.close();
    }
```

I input this data:

```
Hello world
I am a file
Read me until end-of-file.
```

But `hasNextLine())` is always **true**. And as result never print "**finish**"

Comment: `Scanner.hasNextLine()` blocks waiting for a new line, it will only return false if you close the stream (using Ctrl-Z or D as Liel mentions in his answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine. Are you sure you output EOF correctly? Try Ctrl+D (Cmd+D on Mac) or Ctrl+Z on Windows, as mentioned here: [How to send EOF via Windows terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136400/how-to-send-eof-via-windows-terminal)

Answer (score 1):

There is no condition in which the loop will be false, it'll read the lines forever and ever. Consider adding a stop keyword like "stop"

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()) 
{
    String line = scanner.nextLine(); 
    if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) 
    {
        break; 
    }
    //whatever else you have in the loop
}
```

Unless you stop it, it'll always be true. As pointed out by @Aaron

> Scanner.hasNextLine() blocks waiting for a new line, it will only return false if you close the stream (using Ctrl-Z or D as Liel mentions in his answer)

Comment: Your answer doesn't point out *why* OP's code isn't working. It's been pointed out in the comments, but maybe you could add it to your sesponse for completeness' sake?