# Why does hasNext() never ends in Scanner class ? I want to input a sequence of strings using Scanner class

Tags: java

*Basic code for input a series of strings. I trying to use it but this never ends and my solution is not getting printed. What possibly am I doing wrong ?*

```java
while (S.hasNext()) {
    String s = S.next();
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i))) {
            max++;
        }
    }
    if (max > curr) {
        curr = max;
    }
}
System.out.println(curr);
```

Comment: Can you share how you create S ? Did you hook the Scanner up to System.in?

Comment: Scanner S= new Scanner(System.in);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using System.in as your input system, hasNext will always be true because the input stream is never closed. It just waits for more input. Similar question: [Scanner.hasNextLine - always true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63652404/scanner-hasnextline-always-true)