# Can't catch EOFError

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, eoferror

What I expect from making this code is, I input some numbers, then when I input strings the output is 'Not Valid', but when I press enter without putting some value to input, the output is the sum of numbers that we input before. But when I run it on VSCode, whenever I press enter, the result always 'Not Valid', and can't get out of the loop.

For example, I input: `1 2 3 a z` then the output I expect is: `Not valid Not valid 6`

I don't know what is wrong, I just learned python 2 months ago.

```
sum = 0
while True:
    try:
        sum += int(input())
    except ValueError:
        print('Not Valid')
    except EOFError:
        print(sum)
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't input anything, `input()` will return the empty string. Converting it to an integer is invalid, so you get the `ValueError`:

```
>>> input() # next line is empty because I just pressed Enter

'' # `input()` returned the empty string
>>> int('') # can't convert it to an integer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

To trigger `EOFError`, send the EOF signal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>:

```
>>> input()
^DTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
EOFError
```

Here the `^D` represents me pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> on the keyboard (*not* literally typing "^D").

Comment: Ctrl + D maybe not worked for me, but I accidentally press Ctrl + Z and it's worked LOL

Comment: @Shidqi, yes, Ctrl+Z is [the Windows way of sending EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136400/how-to-send-eof-via-windows-terminal), and Ctrl+D is the UNIX way.